# Optimal way to Load Data from SQL Server to DB2

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, db2

We have 40+ Tables present in SQL SERVER DB and we need to copy the data to an IBM DB2 database. What methods do you recommend to accomplish this?

My ANALYSIS:

1. BCP and Data Import - The team is trying to avoid any BCP files
2. Write Stored procedure and use LINKED Server in SQL and insert the data in DB2
3. SSIS Packages to move data.

Please let us know if you have any better way to approach this issue.

Comment: Check if it can be done via DTSWizard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Information Integration, that is known in DB2 as federation? you can do a select in SQL Server directly from DB2, and with this feature you can define a cursor and then just use the LOAD command.